# What are the pre checks have to do when we enable the Multi Threaded Replication? open Bugs or performance issues in multi threaded replication

Tags: mysql

specifications:
using 5 threads,
slave parallel type:
slave-parallel-type=Logical clock,
binlog transaction dependency:
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking=commit order.

bottleneck issues of using Multi Threaded Replication

Comment: Are you having performance problems?  Enable the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) on the Replica to help determine which query/queries are causing the most trouble.